# Continuity of a CDF: what is wrong about my reasoning?

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to prove that a distribution function $F$ is continuous at all points in its domain. By definition, $F$ is right-continuous, so it is enough to prove that it is left-continuous.

Basically we want the limit from the left to agree with $F(x)$: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  F(x - \frac{1}{n}) = P(X < x) = F(x) - P(X=x) = P(X \leq x) = F(x).$$

My problem is this: we can conclude $F$ is continuous at a point $x$ if $P(X=x) = 0$. But suppose we have a distribution with some jump discontinuity at $x$. Clearly $F$ is not continuous at $x$, but aren't all individual points in an interval assigned a probability of zero? Wouldn't that imply that $F$ is continuous at the point where it has a jump discontinuity (obviously wrong)?

Basically my issue is that if you have a probability measure that assigns $0$ to all individual points, then wouldn't this argument imply our $F$ is continuous (even though we only know it to be right-continuous)?

Comment: It is well-known that every CDF is right-continuous. Next to that it is well-known that the CDF of a rv $X$  is continuous if and only if $P(X=x)=0$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$. It that is what you are trying to say here, then nothing is wrong with your reasoning.

Comment: Oh. I think I was mixing things up. I had a counterexample in mind, but I was just thinking of the discrete uniform distribution.